# Knockback in Unity 2D without using AddForce

Tags: unity-game-engine, topdown

I have a player controller script. Since it resets the rigidbody.velocity to something else every frame, I cannot use AddForce to make a knockback. My method of knockback generally works until it hits a collider in which the player position cannot go further into the knockback position it should be because there is a collider not allowing it past into and it just be stuck in the knockback state. This is a top down shooter btw.

Here is the code:
github link: https://github.com/fireWizard23/MFGJ-Summer-2021-ver-1

```
private Vector2 knockbackEndpoint; // Use to store where the endpoint position of the knockback will be

void Update()
{
    currentState = GetNewState();
    DoStateLogic();
  
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(currentState != States.Attacking && currentState != States.InKnockback)
    {
        velocity = Vector2.Lerp(velocity, inputVector * myMobInfo.MovementSpeed, myMobInfo.MovementLerpWeight);
    }
    else
    {
        velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
    
}

private States GetNewState()
{
    switch (currentState)
    {
        default:
        case States.Idle:
            if (velocity != Vector2.zero)
                return States.Walking;
            return States.Idle;
        case States.Walking:
            if (velocity == Vector2.zero) return States.Idle;
            return States.Walking;
        case States.Attacking:
            if (isAttacking < 0) return States.Idle;
            return States.Attacking;
        case States.InKnockback:
            var dist = (knockbackEndpoint - ((Vector2)transform.position)).sqrMagnitude;
            if (dist <= 0.1f * 0.1f)
            {
                if (isAttacking > 0) return States.Attacking;
                knockbackEndpoint = Vector2.zero;
                return States.Idle;
            }
            return States.InKnockback;
    }
}

private void DoStateLogic()
{
    
    // MOVEMENT
    switch(currentState)
    {
        case States.Idle:
        case States.Walking:
            inputVector = GetInputVector();
            if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canAttack == 0)
            {
                Shoot();
            }

            break;
        case States.InKnockback:
            var half = (knockbackEndpoint - (Vector2)transform.position) / 3f;
            myRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + (Vector3)half);
            break;

    }
}
public void GetKnockback(Vector2 knockbackEndpoint)
{
    currentState = States.InKnockback;
    var end = knockbackEndpoint;

    this.knockbackEndpoint = end;

}
private void Shoot()
{
    currentState = States.Attacking;
    isAttacking = 0f;
    canAttack += Time.deltaTime;
    GameObject go = Pooler.Instance.Get("PlayerBullet");
    Vector2 dir = ((Vector2)(MyUtils.CameraUtils.MousePosition - transform.position)).normalized;
    go.GetComponent<IProjectile>()?.Setup(myMuzzlePos.position, dir );
    GetKnockback((-0.5f * dir) + (Vector2)transform.position);
}
```

Comment: What if you add a `else if` to check if the player isn't in knockback state before setting velocity to 0 ?
If you do so you should be able to addForce to your player.

Usually when I do that I create a Coroutine so that the player's movement isn't effective during a set period of time.
GL

Comment: @Kyysel Can you give me an example? I try to write it myself but it's not working.

Comment: Here's what I have tried based on your suggestion: https://pastebin.com/pKLLAFeF - My problem is that it's too floaty when it moves and kinda takes a while to finish. I also changed the Rigidbody2D linear drag to 1, because it doesn't seem to stop without it

Comment: Yup this approximately what I was thinking of !

Answer (score -1):

I used the method of @Kyssel and made a coroutine to revert the currentState back to idle after a few seconds. Also fixed the issue of the AddForce being floaty and lengthy by increasing the AddForce by 10 and making the duration of the knockback short. Full code here: https://pastebin.com/KJVZJSwp

```
public void GetKnockback(Vector2 dir, float scale,float duration=0.1f)
{
    duration = Mathf.Clamp(duration, 0, 1);
    scale = Mathf.Clamp(scale, 0, 5);
    currentState = States.InKnockback;

    myRigidbody.AddForce(dir.normalized * scale * 10f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    MyUtils.Time.SetTimeout(() => {
        myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }, duration, this);

}
```

If you have any tips to improve this please comment so.